# check for duplicate rows (not just a single cell) in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Hello I would like to check for duplicate rows, not just a cell, in google sheets, i would like to apply this formula in conditional formatting so it would highlight the cell

[image]

Here is a sample of what i want to catch

I would like to catch a duplicate row,group,or pair of cells in exact order. Can anybody help me with the formula?

I tried searching and there seems to be no article about it yet, I also tried using countif on both rows and multiply them, but that does not solve it being a pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the following data:
https://ibb.co/sFhjN34

First, range select A1:B1001.
Then, paste the following formula in the custom formula bar.

```
=AND(A1<>"",COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA($A:$A&$B:$B),index(ARRAYFORMULA($A:$A&$B:$B),ROW($A1),))>1)
```

Explaination:

1. `ARRAYFORMULA($A:$A&$B:$B)`
   This is creating a virtual array which concat two columns  A & B.
   E.g. juice      crackers -> juicecrackers
2. index`(ARRAYFORMULA($A:$A&$B:$B),ROW($A1),)`
   Since conditional formating will loop through all rows given the starting range you specify earlier (A1:B1001), this part is trying to loop through `ROW($A_)` such that `index(ARRAYFORMULA($A:$A&$B:$B),ROW($A_),)` will return the combined word.
3. `COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA($A:$A&$B:$B),index(ARRAYFORMULA($A:$A&$B:$B),ROW($A1),))>1)`
   Count every combined word that it specified in this array `ARRAYFORMULA($A:$A&$B:$B)`
   If it countup more than 1, it means duplicated.
4. `A1<>""` For those blank cells, we ignore it.
5. Combine the two conditions. `AND(A1<>"",COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA($A:$A&$B:$B) ....)`

Comment: I have solved mine too using the same commands, I solved it on my own using `=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP($K2&" "&$L2,{Location!$A$2:$A&" "&Location!$E$2:$E,Location!G$2:G},2,false))` this is the core formula i have since added some error trapping and such

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite as perfect as you'd like, but I think this is a start:

`=AND($A1=$A2,$B1=$B2)`

This doesn't highlight the last row of any matches it finds, but it might be serviceable for what you want (ex. if `Row 1` through `Row 3` match, it will only highlight `Row 1` and `Row 2`).

Just change the columns to match the two you're working with, and then if you want it to highlight the entire row, change the `Apply to range` to `A1:Z` or however many columns you have.